# React Native Web integration in existing React Native Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, create-react-app, react-native-web

I have existing react native app. Now I am adding web capability in that code using React Native Web.
My query is regarding the integration approach which is best to be followed.

In React native web documentation, it suggest manually creating integration approach.

Also I was going through multiple online articles , videos, they are suggesting create react app approach.
First create a react web app using CRA and then copy paste folder structure.

What is the good approach to be followed.

Should I first create React App using CRA, and then copy files and dependencies into react native project from react app project ( like react scripts , react dom), rely on CRA script dependecny for build and running server OR should I just install react native web in react native and manually configure babel and other configuration?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.